# freerdp session unknown

Tags: debian, windows, rdp, freerdp

I'm trying to use xfreerdp to connect to our Windows 7 VM from a Debian 10 box and I keep getting the error session[UNKNOWN]. I've tried the xfreerdp 2.0 and 2.2 from backports and even the 3.0 nightly build as of 04/03/2021 and all have the same error.

Here is the command I'm using;

```
/opt/freerdp-nightly/bin/xfreerdp /u:<admin user> /p:<pass> /v:192.168.200.189 /app:"cmd.exe"
```

NOTE: It does work without the '/app:"cmd.exe"' connected but I want to just start the application and then close the connection after leaving that app.

Full error;

```
[14:59:10:453] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state
[14:59:10:453] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpdr
[14:59:10:454] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpsnd
[14:59:10:454] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[14:59:10:454] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rail
[14:59:10:817] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.primitives] - primitives autodetect, using optimized
[14:59:10:829] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_tcp_is_hostname_resolvable:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state
[14:59:10:829] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_tcp_default_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex resetting error state
[14:59:10:844] [18976:18977] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - Certificate verification failure 'unable to get local issuer certificate (20)' at stack position 0
[14:59:10:844] [18976:18977] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - CN = tramontana-PC
[14:59:12:957] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Logon Error Info SESSION_ID [UNKNOWN]
[14:59:12:957] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.x11] - Logon Error Info SESSION_ID [UNKNOWN]
[14:59:12:957] [18976:18977] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - ERRINFO_LOGOFF_BY_USER (0x0000000C):The disconnection was initiated by the user logging off their session on the server.
[14:59:12:957] [18976:18977] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - rdp_set_error_info:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRINFO_LOGOFF_BY_USER [0x0001000C]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue here. Update freerdp from buster-backports:

sudo apt install -t buster-backports libfreerdp-client2-2 freerdp2-x11

Besides, your windows VM should meet some requirements [this](https://superuser.com/questions/955446/remote-desktop-how-can-i-enable-remoteapp-serving-in-windows-10):

```
RemoteApp Tool requires:

    Microsoft .Net Framework 4
    Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate -or-
    Windows 8 Enterprise -or-
    Windows 10 Enterprise or Education -or-
    Windows XP SP3
    It also works with Windows Server 2008 and newer.

Note: If you try to host RemoteApps on any other edition of Windows (eg Win 7/8/10 Professional), the tool will run but RemoteApps will not work. The RDP client will appear to be connecting, then just disappear.
```

Comment: Thanks Howard, I'm running Windows 7 Pro so I must of missed the requirements for this.

Comment: You are welcome. I switched to Windows 7 enterprise from pro, and I upgraded freerdp, it works now.